# Flutter web - FirebaseCloud collection query and get fails with NoSuchMethodError : invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hi Im making app with Flutter for Android, iOS, Web

After a user sign in, Dashboard view loads all documents from collection 'projects'.

But error below arise without any further information.

```
[cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'
```

My code to load documents is..

```
static Future<List<Project>> getProjects(String userID) async {
    try {
      var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      var colRef = db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection("projects")
          .orderBy("modifiedTime", descending: true);
      var documents = await colRef.get();
      var list = documents.docs.map((document) {
        var data = document.data();
        return Project(
            data["owner"],
            data["id"],
            data["name"],
            data["description"],
            data["createdTime"].toDate(),
            data["modifiedTime"].toDate());
      }).toList();

      return list;
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

After researching, I finally can print stacktrace with below code modified slightly from above.

```
      colRef.get().onError((error, stackTrace) 
      {
        print(stackTrace);
        print(error);
      });
```

and result is..

```
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/query_web.dart 127:7                                                                      get
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                    handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44                                    handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13                                    _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 542:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 580:7                                     callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
[cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'
```

After some googling, there is a stackoverflow question and someone said this is version issue and change the version of library from index.html to 7.22.1
Im currently working on 8.2.7, but replacing it to 7.22.1 also give me the same result.

This occurs only in web platform. With same code, Android works just fine. iOS never tested yet.

At last, this is libraries that Im using right now.

pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.0+1"
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
  email_validator: "^1.0.5"
  intl: "^0.16.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0"
  property_change_notifier: "^0.2.0"
```

main.html

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Is there any way I can handle with this issue?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Use ```<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>``` version for now..its still doenst work on flutter web

Comment: @Reign ...7.24.0 worked! Really thank you..